# Why does the lower portion of the tabs is clipped on Mac?

Tags: macos, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm using QML `TabView` for an app on the Mac. The tabs are clipped a bit on their bottom edges - which makes for a "less than perfect" Mac OS X app look & feel.

Has anyone else seen this and is there a fix available? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I might be able to make a patch to the Qt sources to fix this?

Example pic showing how the tabs are truncated/clipped:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to play with margins ?

Comment: I have anchors.margins set to 12 (should be plenty to invoke some kind of gap between tabs and content).  Seems to me like an artifact of the style used on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this with Qt 5.5 and El Capitan. I'm not sure what the fix would be, but you can look into the Desktop `TabViewStyle`:

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Desktop/TabViewStyle.qml

I can't reproduce this with Qt Widgets (the Desktop style uses widgets), so the fix is likely just a tweak in that file.

For information regarding how to contribute patches, see the [Contribution Guidelines](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Contribution_Guidelines).

Comment: I wonder if its something related to the frameOverlap attribute. If I used a bog standard TabViewStyle {} instance in the Tab, then a negative value for frameOverlap offsets the content area - thus avoiding the overdraw.

So I'm now wondering - how can I essentially inherit the existing TabViewStyle but change only the overlap?

Comment: You can't, really. If it were the Base style, it would work, because that is the style that you get as soon as you create your own. That is to say, there's no import that gives you access to the Desktop styles; it's all done internally once you pass a style to `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE`.

Comment: If you have a fix that you think is correct, push it to code review. :)

Comment: good answer - because it means I don't have to waste time trying - i'll get a version of the Qt 5.5.1 code compiled here and fiddle with it.